# reading a json file into R from the internet - trouble with </html> lines

Tags: json, r

I am trying to read the following JSON database into R using the `jsonlite` package.

```
library(jsonlite)
db <- fromJSON("http://www.stbates.org/funguild_db.php", flatten=TRUE)
```

Doing this throws the following error:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <html> <head> <title>funguild_d
                     (right here) ------^
```

Clearly it does not like these characters. Is there a simple work around here I am missing?

Comment: That's not a proper JSON file at all. It's an HTML file that happens to contain data that looks like JSON. I have no idea why someone might server data this way, it seems like a mistake.

Comment: @MrFlick wow. okay, this makes a lot more sense now. Biologists building custom databases, this happens sometimes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MrFlick is right in that it's not a good way to serve data. But as always, there's ways around it. Here I'm using `rvest` to scrape the entire page, then `gsub` to get rid of the first string, which happens to be the final part of the url (minus the .php extension).

```
url <- "http://www.stbates.org/funguild_db.php"

library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

js <- url %>% 
    read_html() %>%
    html_text() 

js <- jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub("funguild_db", "", js))

head(js[, 1:5])

#                       $oid                  taxon taxonomicLevel trophicMode          guild
# 1 58f450f1791497fd28ebfccc Xanthomonas campestris             20  Pathotroph Plant Pathogen
# 2 58f450f1791497fd28ebfccd  Xanthomonas juglandis             20  Pathotroph Plant Pathogen
# 3 58f450f1791497fd28ebfcce         Xanthoparmelia             13 Symbiotroph     Lichenized
# 4 58f450f1791497fd28ebfccf           Xanthopeltis             13 Symbiotroph     Lichenized
# 5 58f450f1791497fd28ebfcd0            Xanthopsora             13 Symbiotroph     Lichenized
# 6 58f450f1791497fd28ebfcd1         Xanthopsorella             13 Symbiotroph     Lichenized
```